# if your press load more button it scrolls back to top of page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, button

I added a load more button onto one of my category pages. I have three posts in a row and after two columns (6 posts) I have a load more button.  The problem is when you press the load more button it scrolls back to the top. I'm assuming because the load more code is in the wrong spot, however I can't find the error. (you have to wrap content in div id=ajax) Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance.

by the way I am using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-load-more/)

```html
<?php
get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel-food');
get_template_part ('inc/food-double-posts');
 
$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
    'cat'=> 10

] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">
        <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();
                
                   if($i % 3 == 0) {
                     echo '</div><div class="row">';
                   }
                ?>
                    <article <?php post_class('col-md-4'); ?> >
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                    </article>
  <?php
                                       
        $i++;
    }?>
  </div>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
       load_more_button();
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

Comment: `I'm assuming because the load more code is in the wrong spot, however I can't find the error` - well ... I can't see any load more code, nor any way to trigger a load more operation in the code you posted

Comment: You wrap the content you want to load more in <div id=ajax> and then to place load_more_button(); where you want button to display

Comment: oh .. well ... can't see the load more code, so can't see why it screws the scroll position